# How can you make dynamc routes with react- router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

please help me. I have a react route that won't render a component but its supposed to render a new component when the html button is cliicked on and set the state to a string. the string console.logs but the page doesn't reload.

```
    const getProfile = async (member) => {
        const addr = dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
        console.log(member)
        props.history.push({
          path: '/member',
          state: { member } 
        });
    }
  
  return (
      <div>
        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>

  <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>

        </tr>})}
      </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Posts);
```

the other component im trying to render is

```
cost Member = (props)=> {  
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { state } = props.location;
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});


useEffect(() => {
  const doEffects = async () => {
    try {
      const pro = socialNetworkContract.members[0]
      console.log(pro)
      const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(pro, { from: accounts[0] });
      setProfile(p)

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
    doEffects();
  }, [profile]);


  return (
    <div class="container">
{profile.name}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Member;
```

My routes.js looks like

```
const Routes = (props) => {
  return (
      <Switch>

      <Route path="/member" exact component={Member} /> 
        <Route path="/posts" exact component={Posts} />
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </Switch>
    
  )
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: no because it still won't render

Comment: If the use case is as such that on click of a button you want to navigate user to a new component, you can use `<Link>` or `<NavLink>` components from reac-router-dom

`
<Link to="/about"><Button>Click here!</Button></Link>
`

you can also pass state like below -

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: You haven't included your routing at all.  You are redirecting to `path: '/member'`.  Does this path exist?

Comment: I have edited ti include the route